# Merging two linked lists yielding seg faults, etc

Tags: c++, pointers, merge, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm creating a linked list of state objects, each of which contains a linked list of resident objects who live in that state. The user reads in a database file and then can choose from a handful of commands, such as finding a person, moving a person, or merging two states into a brand-new state. When I try to merge the people of 2 states, I have to create a new state, move all of the people from the first state's resident list to the new state's resident list and do the same with the resident list of the second state. The people should then appear in the new state's resident list but not in the resident lists of the original states. I'm getting a bunch of errors: when I try merging, I get repetitive free chunk warnings; when the user tries to print out the new state's resident list as a command, no one is listed; further, when the user tries to print either of the original states' resident lists, the first few are printed but then there's a set fault, the core gets dumped, and the program stops running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In my list object:

```
void addLink (Link <type> * data) {
    if (first == NULL) {
        first = data;
        last = data;
    }
    else {
        last->next = data;
        last = data;
    }
}
```

And in my main, if the command typed was "merge"...

```
else if (cmd == "merge") {
    string state1, state2, newstate;
    cin >> state1 >> state2 >> newstate;
    State * ns = state_ls->addLink(new State(newstate))->data;
    Link <State*> * s1 = searchList(state1, state_ls);
    Link <State*> * s2 = searchList(state2, state_ls);
    List <Person*> people1 = s1->data->res_list;
    List <Person*> people2 = s2->data->res_list;
    List <Person*> newres_list = ns->res_list;
    Link <Person*> * temp = people1.first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        newres_list.addLink(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
        }
    temp = people2.first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        newres_list.addLink(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're sharing links between lists. This will most probably be a problem when one of those lists is destroyed. The abundance of pointers suggests that you have more problems with lifetime management. Have you considered not relying so much on pointers?

Comment: The way most other students worked their assignment was with pointers. Pointers are essential for links, and pointers to the data (ie my people and state structs) in my links made many of the earlier commands much easier to test and execute. If there's a specific pointer that should be changed, though, please do let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues in your code which could be the cause of your problems:

1. You don't check the result of `searchList()`. What if the state you enter doesn't exist and it returns NULL? Similarly for `addLink()` if it can fail.
2. `people1`, `people2` and `newres_list` are copies of the original lists. Depending on how these classes are implemented this can be bad or very bad. You probably want to use pointers or references here, like:

   ```
   List <Person*>& people1 = s1->data->res_list;
   List <Person*>& people2 = s2->data->res_list;
   List <Person*>& newres_list = ns->res_list;
   ```
3. If you wish to move persons from the original states to the new state you need to reset the person list head/tail after you move them. Probably something like:

   ```
   s1->person->data->res_list->first = NULL;
   s1->person->data->res_list->last = NULL;
   s2->person->data->res_list->first = NULL;
   s2->person->data->res_list->last = NULL;
   ```

**Update** -- You seem to be a little confused about linked list pointers and adding/removing nodes from multiple lists. If we look at a simple example:

```
List<Person*>* Person1 = new List<Person*>;
List<Person*>* Person2 = new List<Person*>;
List<Person*> List1;
List<Person*> List2;

List1.addLink(Person1);
List1.addLink(Person2);   //Ok: List1 has two persons

List2.addLink(Person1);   //Error: Person1 can't belong to both lists
```

Everything is fine until you try adding a node already in one list to another list. This will "mess up" your node `next` pointers in both lists.

Another confusion seems to be how to move all elements from one list to another. All you have to do is to set the head/tail of both lists, for example to move all nodes from List1 to List2 just do:

```
List2.first = List1.first;
List2.last  = List1.last;
List1.first = NULL;
List1.last  = NULL;
```

You don't need to touch the individual nodes in List1 as you aren't changing their pointer locations. If you want to copy all the nodes from List1 to List2 it is a bit different as you have to create new nodes.

If you are still having problems with your corrected code I would suggest reducing it to a small example that exhibits the problem and post another SO question.

Comment: Wonderful! That solved most of the issues. I keep forgetting that passing pointers only copies things. Thank you! Now that the people are in the new list, if I wanted to delete the people from the old lists...? Is it enough just to iterate through a method that removes the links in the lists, or are there pointers that need to be deleted as well?

Comment: Actually, something odd is happening. I made those three lists references as you said; when I list the new state's people, everything is fine and dandy. When I list the second state's list of people, everyone from that state is still there, which is expected. But when I list the first state's list of people, everyone from BOTH states is now in that list, too. What happened?!